# Readonly in IE still show the cursor while in Chrome not

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have an example using bootstrap datepicker like this code below which in the date picker shows readonly, that prevent the user to modify the date picker. When I run in Chrome and try to pick a date, it works fine . Then when I switch to IE and after I pick the date, it shows a cursor in the input field which may misunderstood the user that they can edit the date, while in fact they can't. How can I hide this cursor in IE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // adding todays date as the value to the datepickers.
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_day = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        var eutoday = curr_day + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;
        var ustoday = curr_month + "-" + curr_day + "-" + curr_year;
        $("div.datepicker input").attr('value', eutoday);
        $("div.usdatepicker input").attr('value', ustoday);

        //calling the datepicker for bootstrap plugin
        // https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
        // http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: new Date()
        });
    });
```

```css
.datepicker input {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-remote="/mmfansler/aQ3Ge/show/">
  <div class="modal-header">
      Header
  </div>
<div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="input-medium" size="16" type="text" readonly ><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>


<br><br><br>

<div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" >
    <input class="input-medium" size="16" type="text" readonly ><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please change your question title. It doesn't describe your problem or question...

Comment: ok thank you, I have changed it,

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
.datepicker input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

to your CSS

Comment: Strange, I had it (seemingly) work, but now it doesn't. Check the updated answer. If that doesn't work either - try adding the disabled tag to the input element. The downside is that you have to remove the disabled attribute before you submit the data IF you are using a form submit, otherwise the data won't get sent.

Comment: actually when I used disabled then it worked in both IE and Chrome, but then if I disable the input then I can not choose the date when I click to the input anymore. It would be nice if I still can click to the input to choose the date